# How to suppress recovery notification in Stackdriver?

Tags: monitoring, google-stackdriver

I have Alerting Policy in Google's Stackdriver which sends a notification when there is an error in the specific log.
For the obvious reason, there is no recovery for such condition, i.e. I don't want to get recovery notification. 
How/If I can suppress Stackdriver recovery notification?

Answer (score 0):

Stack driver alert policy doesn't provide you filter to suppress any specific error.
You can create a filter in your email account to skip specific types of email in your inbox.